# How catch particles with ranged curve guide

Tags: particles, force-fields

I try to simulate aspiration of particles with curve guide force field.

I don't know if the attraction force minimum distance works because for a simple exemple like below,
i can't have attraction when particles approach to curve guide.

Particles use position of curve guide like they have same position.

Min and Max distance of force field have curious behaviour.

[image]

[image]